# Communication with HR recruiter after an interview

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

In case it matters I'm asking about US corporation.

The somewhat long story short:

- I was contacted by a HR recruiter from a large US Health System who found my resume in their database and thought I would be a good fit for a particular open position. I said that I it sounded interesting.
- In about two weeks I was invited for an on-site interview (they apparently do not do phone pre-screening) that I believe went fairly well.
- Feedback from the recruiter was that they liked me but had another candidate to interview and should make a decision in about a week.
- After a couple of follow-ups I was told in (e-mail) today that the decision is expected today or tomorrow.

While I can leave this e-mail unanswered and just wait, I would like to respond with something that confirms my burning desire to get this job while not sounding too desperate.  Since English is my second language I may miss some nuances, so I would welcome community feedback.

I'm thinking about very short reply that minus greeting and signature boils down to the following (literally):

> Thank you for your prompt response.  I will keep my fingers crossed.

It it too informal? Does it betray my desperation?  Any other considerations?

**P.S.** Please note that I'm corresponding with HR person and not directly with the hiring team or their manager. I do not believe he has any say in the decision.  I just want to impress my eagerness on him in the hope that he might convey it to the actual decision maker(s).

Comment: Yes that is too informal.

Comment: At this stage, there is no need to confirm your burning desire as it will not influence the final decision. I wouldn't bother responding at all, to be honest. I would, however, follow up in a couple of days if no decision is forthcoming.

Comment: Your PS isn't really necessary. The answers to the other question adequately covers your situation. It doesn't matter if the person you are following up with is called HR or Hiring Manager or Rockstar Manager. The question is about communicating with *someone* in the company who would inform you whether you got the job or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

> Thank you for your prompt response. I eagerly await the decision.

This conveys your desire for the job without being informal or sounding overly desperate.